# Convert a String of 6 into mm/dd/yyyy h:m with conditions

Tags: java, rest

I'm developing an API in which one of the object should satisfy the below:
I've a column in Postgress DB as :

```
input = 201800
Input(column -datatype is character[6]) 201801
                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
                                        201812
```

Requirement :

- Check if the input is current year
- check if the last 2 digits are zeros , then ignore 
  if it is 201802 : dd=01(always), 02(Month) and 2018(year)
  after checking the conditions, if it satisfies display like this :

For Ex: `input = 201803` then o/p should in MM/DD/YYYY h:m format
Always month is 01 for month in between (01-12),O/P =  `01/03/2018 12:00`

I tried this, but didn't gibe O/P as per ,y requirement:

```
public class sample {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String input= "201700" + "00";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            Date d = sdf1.parse(input);
            System.out.print(d);
            String formateDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm").format(d);

            System.out.print(formateDate);
        } catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Through Java program, O/P is : 11/30/2016 12:00

Comment: Desired out put is since last two digits are zeros, should be ignore if lasw two were in between 01-12 then o/p : 01/(01-12)/2018

Comment: Don't you think your date format is incorrect? Why don't you expect `"201801"` if you enter a six digits date? Why not enter only `"2018"` if you only want to specify the year and let the default month.

Comment: the 6 digits value comes from the DB. I need to to consider "201801" as Year : 2018 and Month : 01 and Date always 01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a method `mapDate()` that is actually verifying your condition and return the wanted output. You just have to pass the value as parameter to the method. See the example below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result1 = mapDate("201802"+"00");
        System.out.print("result: " + result1 + "\n");
        String result2 = mapDate("201702"+"02");
        System.out.print("result: " + result2 + "\n");
        String result3 = mapDate("201802"+"02");
        System.out.print("result: " + result3);
    }

    public static String mapDate(String value){
        String myDate;
        myDate = "";
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        String thisYear = format1.format(new Date());
        if(!value.substring(value.length() - 2).equals("00") && value.substring(0, 4).equals(thisYear))
            myDate = "01/" + value.substring(4, 6) + "/" + value.substring(0, 4) + " 12:00";
        return myDate;
    }
}
```

The ouput of this example is:

```
result: 
result: 
result: 01/02/2018 12:00
```

Comment: Thankyou, Sample looks matching to my requirement.I'm applying this logic in my coding, and will update you soon

Comment: My pleasure! I was not sure what type of return you would like to have when it is not matching your requirements so I just return empty `String`, however feel free to return whatever seems the most convenient for you.

Comment: Jonathan, I need your help

Comment: public List<VLCAndMgmtMetricsDTO> getVLCMetricsByStatus() {
    String vlcPeriod = vlcObj.getPeriod();
    if (vlcPeriod!= null){
      String input= mapDate(vlcPeriod+"00");
      vlcMetricsValue.setPeriod(input);
     
    }else {
     vlcMetricsValue.setPeriod(Constants.EMPTY_STRING);
         
    }

Comment: When I included your code in my method, input is displaying null. Can you please help me to correct. I tried printing vlcPeriod from DB and it is displaying correctly. Please correct me where I'm doing wrong

Comment: Sure, Apprecite it! I couldn't send more code of mine here. Let me know. I can send you

Comment: if (vlcPeriod!= null){
     try{
      System.out.println(vlcPeriod);
      String input1= vlcPeriod+"00";
      System.out.println("input1::::" + input1);
      String output= mapDate(input1+"00");
      System.out.println("input::::" + output);
      vlcMetricsValue.setPeriod(output);
     }
     
     Output:  201802
     input1::::20180200
     input::::

Comment: You will have to handle the result that you want to ignore, in the method `mapDate()` we return `""` (null) if there is no match. So instead `vlcMetricsValue.setPeriod(input);` put `if(input != null && !input.isEmpty()) { vlcMetricsValue.setPeriod(input); }`, like this you will be sure to run this line of code only if there is a match.

Comment: Sweet my pleasure! Glad you got it!